# Creating and initialising a 2D Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, random, multidimensional-array

I haven't used 2D Arrays before so apologies for any 'obvious statements'. 
I want to create a **2D Array** for a **15 by 20** 'table' and want the following to be applied:

- I want each row to be a **separate Array**.
- I want each row to have random **0's and 1's** generated

The code I have created creates the 15 x 20 table but not sure if each row is an Array and **can't figure** out how to put random 0's and 1's. Help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
    for (int i=0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < ar[i].length; j++) {
        ar[i][j] = 0;
        System.out.print(" " + ar[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
int cols = 15;
int rows = 20;

Random rand = new Random();

int[][] myArray = new int[rows][cols];

for (int i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
        myArray[i][j] = rand.nextInt(2);
        System.out.print(" " + myArray[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

Comment: Oh that was simple. Cheers for the help!

Comment: I managed to change it so it showed random number from 1 to 10, which I want. But I want to know how do I limit the number of times as number appear, to 4??

Answer (score 1):

Use `nextInt` method.

```
myArray[i][j] = rand.nextInt(2); // we are using 2 cause nextInt generates random number between 0 to 2 exclusive.
```